# Can we use mathematical induction within a proof by mathematical induction?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, induction

My question is short and concise. It is that while proving a theorem or a result by induction can we use induction in between the proof on an intermediate expression.

I've encountered this many times that while proving by induction sometimes we land to an expression wherein I think proving that expression using induction can be helpful rather than carrying out some difficult manipulations.

I think that doing this is logically justified because the intermediate expression which we receive can also be asked to be proved as an independent result. And many a times while manipulating those lengthy expression we also use some of the properties which are themselves proven using induction or any other method of proof.

So is this process justified. One more thing is that if it is justified and we can use induction in between a proof by induction, then it follows that we can do that multiple times and may be we end up at a greatly simplified expression.

Please and let me know that whether this is worth doing?

As an example I just tried this (which I have still not proved) - $$(n+1)^{2n+1}< n^n(n+2)^{n+1} $$ After a series of steps within inductive step I reached to this which I have to prove- $$\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^k>\left(\frac{k+2}{k+3}\right)^{k+2}$$
May be the manipulations are simple enough which I can not figure out(or don't want to) but I think I can use induction to prove this result ( which may make this a bit more complex, anyways may be if applied somewhere else it would make that simpler )

Thanks.

Comment: if you have encountered it many times, can you then give an example?

Comment: What makes you think it will be unjustified?

Comment: if you prove something by induction it is already proved, it doesnt care if this happen inside than a longer proof.

Comment: Nothing... Just wanted to confirm because it sounds odd at first.

Comment: To avoid sounding odd and also confusing notation (the induction variable being $k$, $n$, or whatever), you have already given the solution: the intermediate expression can be proved as an independent result.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is ok to do an inductive proof to prove something that you need as part of another inductive proof.  For example, starting with the Peano Axioms, you can prove commutativity of addition ($\forall x \forall y \ x+y=y+x$) by induction on $x$, and you can prove the base ($\forall y \ 0+y=y+0$) by induction on $y$.